# Как подсветить или изменить стиль некоторых букв в строке

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как сделать подобие подсветки синтаксиса?

На входе есть строка 1235aa2323aa

```
<span class="input_text" contenteditable="true">1235aa2323aa</span>
```

На выходе должно получится что-то вроде **1235**aa**2323**aa, где цифры и буквы имеют разные css стили которые применяются при вводе символов.

Comment: А это небольшой такой кусок текста или планируете что-то масштабов JsFiddle ?)

Comment: Это буквально строка из 6-7 символов...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой костыль придумался... поставить поверх вашего элемента прозрачный textarea (input), ровно с теми же размерами и шрифтом, а при вводе текста - обновлять его в span. Проблема в том, что [caret-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color#Browser_compatibility) плохо поддерживается браузерами.

```js
let inp = document.querySelector('.input_text');
let invis = document.querySelector('.invis');

inp.innerHTML = color(inp.innerText);

invis.addEventListener('input', function() {
  inp.innerHTML = color(this.value);
  this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight + 2) + 'px';
});

function color(txt) {
  return txt.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span class="number">$1</span>')
}
```

```css
.input_text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #22282b;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #f7ed7e;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
}

.number {
  color: #ed593c;
}

.invis {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  caret-color: #f7ed7e;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative">
  <span class="input_text" spellcheck="false" contenteditable>1235aa2323aa</span>
  <textarea class="invis" spellcheck="false">1235aa2323aa</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Через replace искать что подсветить и делать обертку с нужными стилями https://jsfiddle.net/1jm2cfqz/

```
document.querySelector('.input_text').innerHTML = document.querySelector('.input_text').innerHTML.replace(/\d/g, '<b>$&</b>')
```

Comment: Да, только сразу <b class="my">$&</b>, чтобы потом css стили прописать

Comment: @Чипекве `contenteditable` намекает, что оно должно работать и в процессе печати. А обновлять innerHTML и держать курсор на месте - задачка муторная. В этом и сложность))

Comment: Так используйте input с onChange, в чём проблема?

Comment: @AlexanderP Текст внутри input нельзя стилизовать кусками...

Answer (score 0):

Обернул каждый символ в тэг

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".my-text").keydown(function(event) {
    const parElem = $(".my-text")
    event.preventDefault();
    let newEl;
    const kCode = event.keyCode;
    if (kCode >= 48 && kCode <= 57) {
        newEl = `<span class="num">${String.fromCharCode(kCode)}</span>`;
        } else {
          newEl =`<span class="str">${String.fromCharCode(kCode)}</span>`;
        }
    if(kCode === 8) {
      $('span').last().remove();
    } else {
      parElem.html(parElem.html() + newEl)
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
.num {
  color: red;
}
.str {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="my-text" contenteditable="true">
  text
</p>
```

Нужно доработать поведение для других keyCode-ов, но вроде-бы работает